# How to create InAppWebViewController (for flutter_inappwebview)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I use [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) package in my flutter application.

How can I create [InAppWebViewController](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_inappwebview/latest/flutter_inappwebview/InAppWebViewController-class.html) without creating [InAppWebView](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_inappwebview/latest/flutter_inappwebview/InAppWebView-class.html)?
There is a [InAppWebViewController.fromPlatform](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_inappwebview/latest/flutter_inappwebview/InAppWebViewController/InAppWebViewController.fromPlatform.html) method for this, but I do not understand how to use it.

Can anyone give example?

Comment: Why would you need to construct it manually?

Comment: @DhafinRayhan I need it to run javascript code. So I do not need InAppWebView, I need only InAppWebViewController.